# Next.js trying to push data from input value into json, but onSubmit doesn't work at all

Tags: javascript, json, forms, input, next.js

I'm trying to put input value into json file, but submit button doesn't work, can you help me with it?

```
import PcosData from "/data/pcos.json"; 
import {useEffect} from "react"; 
import { useState } from "react";


export default function adminPcos() {

    // const CreateMePanel = () => {
        const [title, setTitle] = useState(PcosData["pcos-first"].title);
        const [time, setTime] = useState(PcosData["pcos-first"].time);


        const handleSubmit = (e) => {
            PcosData["pcos-first"].title = title;
            PcosData["pcos-first"].time = time;

        }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>hello world</h1>

            {PcosData["pcos-first"].map((pcosdata) => (
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} key={ pcosdata.id } method="post">
                    <input type="text" name={title} defaultValue={pcosdata.title} onChange={(e) => setTitle({text: e.target.value})}/>
                    <input type="text" name={time} defaultValue={pcosdata.time} onChange={(e) => setTime({text: e.target.value})}/>
                    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
                </form>
            ))}

        </div>
    )
}
```

i checked all of the functions, variables, but didn't find any errors

Comment: If you console.log inside `handleSubmit`, do you see it in the console?

Comment: Okay, i've deleted prevent default, and now submit works)) But the data in json doesn't change( After I click submit, the page just reload, and that's all

Comment: What JSON file are you refering to? I don't see anything related in the code above

Comment: import PcosData from "/data/pcos.json";
import {useEffect} from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

Comment: I recommend you to add relevant data to your question, don't leave it as a comment.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you trying to write the file contents to disk? If that's the case, you won't be able to do that from the client side, you will need to do it from your backend.